# How to multiply select box option and a field dynamically in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a select box like

```html
<select name="abc">
  <option> 0 </option>
  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 2 </option>
  <option> 3 </option>
</select>
```

and a normal text value like 1000.
i want to multiply 1000 with the option being selected in the text box dynamically without form and submit button.
How would i be able to do that.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Use ajax. did you try?

Comment: No. i am not able to get the ajax right.

Comment: i have an ajax to multiply two text fields value

Comment: @DeepanshuSingh , you mean user select any option from the select box and that value will be multiply with some other value written in the text box and you want to display the multiplication of both the values somewhere .  am i right ?

Comment: This is basic "Math 101". I don't see much effort put into this question.

Comment: @punit. Yes. basically. i want to multiply the values of the select box with a numerical value changing dynamically in a variable

Comment: Why to use ajax thn.   answer given by @Ruchish Parikh is good. using javascript function you can easily achieve it . .

Answer (score 2):

Use below code.

```js
function fun(val)
{
  document.getElementById("ansval").value = val * 1000;
}
```

```html
<select name="abc" onChange="fun(this.value)">
  <option value="0"> 0 </option>
  <option value="1"> 1 </option>
  <option value="2"> 2 </option>
  <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="ansval" id="ansval">
```

Comment: if i want to replace this thousand with a php variable.

Comment: how could i do it?

Comment: if you are adding <script> in php file then you can write php code in javascript. <?php echo 1000 ?>

Answer (score 0):

make form1.html as below.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function myFunction(val) {
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_create.php?name="+val, true);
        xmlhttp.send();


        /*xmlhttpCreate.open("GET", "ajax_create.php?name=" + val, true);  // Open the request
        xmlhttpCreate.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttpCreate.send();*/
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="abc" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
  <option> 0 </option>
  <option> 1 </option>
  <option> 2 </option>
  <option> 3 </option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

now make ajax_create.php as below

```
<?php
$value=$_GET['name']*1000;

echo $value;    
?>
```

its working fine enjoy.

Comment: if i want to replace this thousand with a php variable. how could i do it?

Comment: you have to pass ajax request then you can do it.

Comment: please try above edited code in php you can use like below.

Comment: <?php
  
$value=$_POST['name']*1000;
   
echo $value;    
?>

Comment: make php file ajax_create.php and write above commented php code inside it.

Comment: please see my updated answer i tested it in my local server and give it to you.

Comment: when you change the value of the select box at that time you see the result.

Comment: can i store the returned ajax response in a php variable instead of alert box and then print it on webpage?

Comment: yes you can store in $_SESSION VARIABLE in php file or you can also use innerHTML METHOD TO DISPLAY IT

Comment: yes i tried it with session but if i do it dynamically for more values it can create many sessions

Comment: and i can't unset the session as i have to take the value to another page.

Comment: use denine to store value

Comment: $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];

echo $z;

Comment: $GLOBALS may be used.

Comment: i 'l also have to refresh the page if i want the session value to be displayed  and i was looking forward to not refreshing the page

Comment: see above denine and globals

Comment: localstorage of html 5 also used to store value and you can also use it in multiple page

Comment: it's working but still after refreshing the page. If there's any solution you can provide that i don't have to refresh the page for seeing the result. ?

Comment: e.g.// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

Comment: its a javascript session which is used in all the page.you can also use cookie of javascript as well as php for storing value

Comment: window of javascript also use to store value and you can use it in multiple page.

Comment: window.variableName=value;

Comment: I have added a automatic refresh code here and its working fine now.. Thanks a lot for the help